# How do you toggle a boolean in a postgres table using knex in one query?

Tags: postgresql, boolean, toggle, knex.js

Is it possible to toggle a boolean value in a postgres table using knex in a single query and return the new value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
await knex('table').update({ 
    boolCol: knex.raw('NOT ??',  ['boolCol]) 
  }).returning('boolCol');
```